# Create NuGet package from folder

Tags: nuget, teamcity, azure-functions, nuget-package

I need to package an Azure function app that we've built in TeamCity as a Nuget package for deployment via Octopus Deploy. Standard practice would be to use MSBuild and OctoPack but with Azure Functions this will not work as the function.json files are created after the build is complete and they would therefore not be included in any package that OctoPack creates.

So I need to build first and then create a package from the \bin\Release\net471 folder. Would be grateful to hear peoples opinions on the best way to acheive this?

Comment: Artifacts dependencies in TeamCity doesn't work for you?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by that? Yes, I can use an artifact dependency to use the artifacts in a subsequent build step but it doesn't help me to package them.

Comment: In the end I went with octo.exe using a start directory of \bin\Release\net471 which saved me having to create a nuspec file as I would have had to if using the NuGet CLI or dotnet pack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with octo.exe using a start directory of \bin\Release\net471 which saved me having to create a nuspec file as I would have had to if using the NuGet CLI or dotnet pack